# PHP - include a php file and also send query parameters

Tags: php, parameters, include

I have to show a page from my php script based on certain conditions. I have an if condition and am doing an "include" if the condition is satisfied.

```
if(condition here){
  include "myFile.php?id='$someVar'";
}
```

Now the problem is the server has a file "myFile.php" but I want to make a call to this file with an argument (id) and the value of "id" will change with each call.

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: What does myFile.php actually do in your case? Unless you request the include over HTTP, you can't add parameters to the filename, but you could influence its behaviour via a global variable of some sort.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Imagine the include as what it is: A copy & paste of the contents of the included PHP file which will then be interpreted. There is no scope change at all, so you can still access $someVar in the included file directly (even though you might consider a class based structure where you pass $someVar as a parameter or refer to a few global variables).

Comment: Also note: $_GET will be the same for all included files. So if that is where your query parameters are stored, it will still see them.

Also note: it is not the function, in a class.

Comment: This very simple explanation cleared up hours worth of problems I was having.

Answer (score 60):

You could do something like this to achieve the effect you are after:

```
$_GET['id']=$somevar;
include('myFile.php');
```

However, it sounds like you are using this include like some kind of function call (you mention calling it repeatedly with different arguments).

In this case, why not turn it into a regular function, included once and called multiple times?

Comment: I agree, this definitely sounds like it should be a function call instead of an include.

Comment: Are you code and `include("myFile.php?id=$somevar");` identical?

Comment: Note: `include("myFile.php?...` does not work as intended.

Answer (score 37):

An include is just like a code insertion. You get in your included code the exact same variables you have in your base code. So you can do this in your main file :

```
<?
    if ($condition == true)
    {
        $id = 12345;
        include 'myFile.php';
    }
?>
```

And in "myFile.php" :

```
<?
    echo 'My id is : ' . $id . '!';
?>
```

This will output :

> My id is 12345 !

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to do this is like this

index.php

```
<?php $active = 'home'; include 'second.php'; ?>
```

second.php

```
<?php echo $active; ?>
```

You can share variables since you are including 2 files by using "include"

Comment: quick and dirty. love it!

Answer (score 7):

If you are going to write this include manually in the PHP file - the answer of **Daff** is perfect.

Anyway, if you need to do what was the initial question, here is a small simple function to achieve that:

```
<?php
// Include php file from string with GET parameters
function include_get($phpinclude)
{
    // find ? if available
    $pos_incl = strpos($phpinclude, '?');
    if ($pos_incl !== FALSE)
    {
        // divide the string in two part, before ? and after
        // after ? - the query string
        $qry_string = substr($phpinclude, $pos_incl+1);
        // before ? - the real name of the file to be included
        $phpinclude = substr($phpinclude, 0, $pos_incl);
        // transform to array with & as divisor
        $arr_qstr = explode('&',$qry_string);
        // in $arr_qstr you should have a result like this:
        //   ('id=123', 'active=no', ...)
        foreach ($arr_qstr as $param_value) {
            // for each element in above array, split to variable name and its value
            list($qstr_name, $qstr_value) = explode('=', $param_value);
            // $qstr_name will hold the name of the variable we need - 'id', 'active', ...
            // $qstr_value - the corresponding value
            // $$qstr_name - this construction creates variable variable
            // this means from variable $qstr_name = 'id', adding another $ sign in front you will receive variable $id
            // the second iteration will give you variable $active and so on
            $$qstr_name = $qstr_value;
        }
    }
    // now it's time to include the real php file
    // all necessary variables are already defined and will be in the same scope of included file
    include($phpinclude);
}
```

?>

I'm using this variable variable construction very often.

Answer (score 3):

I know this has been a while, however, Iam wondering whether the best way to handle this would be to utilize the be session variable(s)

In your myFile.php you'd have

```
<?php 

$MySomeVAR = $_SESSION['SomeVar'];

?>
```

And in the calling file

```
<?php

session_start(); 
$_SESSION['SomeVar'] = $SomeVAR;
include('myFile.php');
echo $MySomeVAR;

?>
```

Would this circumvent the "suggested" need to Functionize the whole process?

Comment: You want to make it a function so you don't initiate a bunch of requests. The problem isn't how to get the information to the included PHP -- OP's method already achieves that.

Answer (score 3):

In the file you include, wrap the html in a function.

```
<?php function($myVar) {?>
    <div>
        <?php echo $myVar; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

In the file where you want it to be included, include the file and then call the function with the parameters you want.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does wrapping markup in a function relate to the given problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have ran into this when doing ajax forms where I include multiple field sets.  Taking for example an employment application.  I start out with one professional reference set and I have a button that says "Add More".  This does an ajax call with a $count parameter to include the input set again (name, contact, phone.. etc)  This works fine on first page call as I do something like:

```
<?php 
include('references.php');`
?>
```

User presses a button that makes an ajax call `ajax('references.php?count=1');`  Then inside the references.php file I have something like:

```
<?php
$count = isset($_GET['count']) ? $_GET['count'] : 0;
?>
```

I also have other dynamic includes like this throughout the site that pass parameters.  The problem happens when the user presses submit and there is a form error.  So now to not duplicate code to include those extra field sets that where dynamically included, i created a function that will setup the include with the appropriate GET params.

```
<?php

function include_get_params($file) {
  $parts = explode('?', $file);
  if (isset($parts[1])) {
    parse_str($parts[1], $output);
    foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
      $_GET[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  include($parts[0]);
}
?>
```

The function checks for query params, and automatically adds them to the $_GET variable.  This has worked pretty good for my use cases.

Here is an example on the form page when called:

```
<?php
// We check for a total of 12
for ($i=0; $i<12; $i++) {
  if (isset($_POST['references_name_'.$i]) && !empty($_POST['references_name_'.$i])) {
   include_get_params(DIR .'references.php?count='. $i);
 } else {
   break;
 }
}
?>
```

Just another example of including GET params dynamically to accommodate certain use cases.  Hope this helps.  Please note this code isn't in its complete state but this should be enough to get anyone started pretty good for their use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$GLOBALS` to solve this issue as well.

```
$myvar = "Hey";

include ("test.php");


echo $GLOBALS["myvar"];
```

Comment: that worked .
but i need to use different values for the include, what sshould i do //

Answer (score 1):

***Try this also***

*we can have a function inside the included file then we can call the function with parametrs.*

our file for include is `test.php`

```
<?php
function testWithParams($param1, $param2, $moreParam = ''){
    echo $param1;
}
```

*then we can include the file and call the function with our parameters as a variables or directly*

`index.php`

```
<?php
include('test.php');
$var1 = 'Hi how are you?';
$var2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
testWithParams($var1, $var2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is on this question, when using `include('somepath.php');` and that file contains a function, the var must be declared there as well. The inclusion of `$var=$var;` won't always work. Try running these:

one.php:

```
<?php
    $vars = array('stack','exchange','.com');

    include('two.php'); /*----- "paste" contents of two.php */

    testFunction(); /*----- execute imported function */
?>
```

two.php:

```
<?php
    function testFunction(){ 
        global $vars; /*----- vars declared inside func! */
        echo $vars[0].$vars[1].$vars[2];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very clear, but if you want to **include** the php file (add the source of that page to yours), you just have to do following :

```
if(condition){
    $someVar=someValue;
    include "myFile.php";
}
```

*As long as the variable is named $someVar in the myFile.php*

Comment: Please share more details. Why do you need to use an `if` condition?

Answer (score -1):

I was in the same situation and I needed to include a page by sending some parameters... But in reality what I wanted to do is to redirect the page... if is the case for you, the code is:

```
<?php
   header("Location: http://localhost/planner/layout.php?page=dashboard"); 
   exit();
?>
```

Comment: If you wanted to use something completely different, go for it. But this answer does not look related to the given initial problem to me