# Getting GET/POST result from third PHP page

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I have the following pages:

- **webservice.php** - it has a webservice used to handle all the possible GET and POST variables sent to it, returning a string as result.
- **form_page.php** - the page with a form whose action redirects to **table_result.php**.
- **table_result.php** - on this page, there is a table which should be filled up with the results from **webservice.php**.

My question is: if the `GET/POST` variables' values are only available on **table_result.php** (after the form data has been submitted), how can I send them to **webservice.php** and get the result to fill up the table without leaving **table_result.php**? IT is important to note that on **webservice.php** there are a bunch of `if (isset($_GET["var_name"]))` to formulate a database query and return the result on a string, as said before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871858/php-pass-variable-to-next-page

Comment: This question could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-url-php

Comment: I am not understanding your use case.  If you are having the form submitted and actually doing a page redirection, why do you require a web service call at all? Why would you not just get the information needed as part of of the initial page load on `table_result.php`?

Comment: losthorse, The link provided as possible duplicate only shows the classical get/post operations.

MikeBrant, I needed to do that because I must use this web service page through which I may access the system information. It receives post or get variables and returns an answer upon their values.

@Michas Your suggestion solved the problem. Thanks! Actually, an answer below the green-checked one shared the link '[how to submit a form using php](http://thehungrycoder.com/general/how-to-submit-a-form-using-php-curl-fsockopen.html)' which I followed step-by-step to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of the `$_GET`, use `$_REQUEST`, as this would make it available via both POST and GET. Then you can just use the search [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4315271/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-included-file) and find your answer