# PHP include() with GET attributes (include file.php?q=1)

Tags: php, include, get

I want to `include()` a php file located on my server, with additional GET attributes.
But it won't work:

```
include('search.php?q=1');
```

The error it gives:

```
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening './search.php?q=1' for inclusion
```

Seems like it tries to open a file literally named 'search.php?q=1' instead of opening the 'search.php' file and sending it the GET attributes.

*Note that it does work if I don't put any GET attributes:

```
include('search.php');
```

Comment: It can not work. You can't use query parameters there.

Comment: *(reference)* http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: What makes you think it should work? GET is an HTTP method, i.e. it used by the HTTP protocol, which is handled by your web server. `include` on the other hand, just reads and interprets the file directly from the file system, no web server involved. These are two different processes.

Comment: @Felix `include` can use URIs if `allow_url_include` and `allow_url_fopen` is enabled.

Comment: @Gordon: Ok, yes I didn't think about that. But then you would have to pass an absolute URI I assume.

Comment: @Felix yes of course and it's disabled on most shared hosters for security reasons anyways

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - include a php file and also send query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232097/php-include-a-php-file-and-also-send-query-parameters)

Answer (score 29):

You don't want to do this: You'd have to do a http request to be able to pass GET parameters. A PHP script you call in this way will run in a separate PHP process.

The optimal way is to include the file locally:

```
include('search.php');
```

and to pass any parameters to it manually, like e.g.

```
$q = "1";
include('search.php');  // expects `$q` parameter
```

or, more cleanly, putting whatever you have in `search.php` into a function or class that you can call with a parameter:

```
include('search.php');  // defines function my_search($q)  
my_search(1);
```

Comment: Or even better use a class structure. `include('search.php'); $search = new Search($q);`

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski because throwing in some class(es) just makes everything magically better somehow right? right?

Comment: Yes, encapsulation is important. Sharing global variables between files is just asking for incredibly hard to diagnose bugs and generally unmaintainable code.

Answer (score 23):

The *easy* solution is to set your GET value before you include the file.

```
$_GET['q'] = 1;
include('search.php);
```

Comment: Writing into the GET array feels a bit dirty. But it will work

Comment: I agree, this is just a fast&dirty way to do that.

Comment: Tip: Check if your script does not access $_GET['q'], otherwise writing to this superglobal can lead to unwanted results.

Answer (score 4):

Try rewrite $_GET variable.

```
$oldget=$_GET;
$_GET=array('q'=>'1');
include('search.php');
$_GET=$oldget;
```

Answer (score 2):

In effect, writing into the `$_GET` array is a bit dirty and not necessary.
You could simply set a variable in your page before the `include` statement:

```
$q=1;
include("search.php");
```

this way, the `$q` variable will be visible in your included page and can (obviously) be set differently in any including page.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine!! Thank you

Set the var before the "include" statement

```
$q=1;
include("search.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe an other option, although it comes with its own limitations, using AJAX-injection into a div.. most simple way to to this is with jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>$('#box').load('search.php?q=1');</script>

<div ID="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If like me you needed this to be permanently in the 'include' link it can be done with jQuery.

The solution I used recently was as follows:

First, declare the location of the div to be populated by the included file:

```
<div id="imgdiv"> </div>
```

Then add a jQuery call to populate it, but insert your GET variables with PHP:

```
<script>                
window.onload = function(){     
        $("#imgdiv").load('php/show-img.php?id=<?php echo $i; ?>&name=<?php echo $name; ?>');           
}
</script>
```

Hopefully that will be sufficient to get it working, assuming a java enabled browser is used of course.