# PHP include with a get variable

Tags: php, include

So I've search far and wide to try and find an example of this but found nothing. It seems like a simple thing however I continue to get errors.

Essentially what I've got is:

```
<?php 
    $articleCount = 3;
    include('/newsArticles.php?id=$articleCount'); 
?>
```

It seems fairly self explanatory. What I need is an include that I can pass a value on into the file which I can then grab with $_GET['id'].

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - include a php file and also send query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232097/php-include-a-php-file-and-also-send-query-parameters)

Comment: A query string is only meaningful in the context of an HTTP request, an include is not such; its a simple read from the local file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a query string (Something like ?x=yyy&vv=www) onto an include like that. Fortunately your includes have access to all the variables before them, so if `$_GET['id']` is defined before you call:

```
include('/newsArticles.php');
```

Then newsArticles.php will also have access to `$_GET['id'];`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a `$_GET` variable. Just set it, and reference it in your included file.

Your included file will have access to `$articleCount` without any additional work needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$_GET['id'] = 3;
include('/newsArticles.php');
```

Comment: Except the `newsArticles.php` file is unlikely to be at the filesystem root; so make sure that you're using the path to your web route

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including a script it would seem as though you have access to the script itself. Even if you don't have access to the script you can edit the $_GET variable from within the script you showed above, like this:

```
<?php
    $_GET['id'] = 3; // or $_GET['id'] = $articleCount;
    include('/newsArticles.php');
?>
```

That's because the script newsArticles.php has the same access to the $_GET variable, unless the script was specifically created so that it extracts the variables from the URL.

Try it.