# including a file is failing in php

Tags: php

I ma having this code

```
<?php include ("commentsdisplay.php?postid=".$activity[$i]['PostId']."&category=".$activity[$i]['Category']) ; ?>
```

but php is generating a fatal error. Is this syntax wrong?

```
 Warning: include(commentsdisplay.php?postid=17&amp;category=article): 
 failed to open stream: No error in C:\wamp\www\Spiralblog\home.php on line  
 79
 Call Stack
 #  Time    Memory  Function    Location
 1  0.0015  253760  {main}( )   ..\home.php:0
```

Comment: What's the fatal error?

Comment: FYI that is not an fatal error. A fatal error would occur if you used `require()` or `require_once()`

Comment: @Daan okay.. sorry for the wrong word ... but still the stream has failed to open so that is not less a error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass parameters to an include like that.

Read the first answer on this question posted a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1232114/4296515

> Quote from : @Daff
>
> Imagine the include as what it is: A copy & paste of the contents of the included PHP file which will then be interpreted. There is no scope change at all, so you can still access $someVar in the included file directly (even though you might consider a class based structure where you pass $someVar as a parameter or refer to a few global variables).

Comment: aha!!!! but what if I want to reuse the page somewhere else??? as you can see its the comments display page.. and I want to reuse the code in places where there is a need for the comments to be displayed.. so if I follow what is in that previous answer then the code will be bound only to one place..

Comment: Well, to answer that question we'd need a lot more info like what framework you're using, how you're building your HTML etc. so you might want to create another question for that purpose.