# include file passing a parameter

Tags: php

I am using ob_* functions to build some content that will be then passed to an HTML template and printed in pdf format with MPDF.

I need to include some contents coming from another php file. The file I need to include will run a query and echo some data in a table based on a id parameter.
Normally in my application I use ajax to load this file in the right place but ob_* functions output the data before AJAX can do its stuffs (see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717214/ob-start-and-jquery-document-ready) on this point) so I am looking for a workaround. 
The best idea I had is to use php include to do the trick. The code in my mind would look like:

```
foreach($listaz as $l){
    include "bp/businessplan.php?id=$l";
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work (I am aware of how include works as stated [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232097/php-include-a-php-file-and-also-send-query-parameters)) since I get this error:

> Warning: include(bp/businessplan.php?id=AZ000000213): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/jdev/creditmanager/sofferenze/soff.php on line 1000

`$listaz` will contain the list of parameters to pass to the file and the array is like the following:

```
array(
    [0]=>AZ000000213
)
```

(in this case just one item)
So the question is:
**How do I get to include the content of the businessplan.php file in the main php file as many times as the values in the array printing it in a specific place in the main php file (appending it into a div one after the other)?**

Comment: If `listaz` contains numeric keys - why do you use `'id_az'`?

Comment: you are right. my error but the error still remains. Editing the question :)

Comment: Did you try it with `file_get_contents` and the absolute URL or just by calling the script with `cURL` rather than trying to include it?

Comment: I thought about flie_get_contents but I think I'll get the same issue with the param. What do you mean with absolute url?

Comment: `http://www.example.com/my/script.php?test='.$id'`. To use this you need to have [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) enabled

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try add absolute path to your file with `__DIR__` constant (http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) something like this:

   `include __DIR__."/bp/businessplan.php?id=$l";`

it must solve your path issue.

2. And if you want get content many times you can try use `return` instead ob_* functions. Please see my example below:

*file test.php*

```
<?php
$r = '';
for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
  $_GET['id'] = $i;
  $r .= include 'businessplan.php';
}

echo $r;
```

*file businessplan.php*

```
<?php
return 'your html here'.$_GET['id'].PHP_EOL;
```

And when I run test.php it show me this lines:

```
your html here0
your html here1
your html here2
your html here3
your html here4
your html here5
your html here6
your html here7
your html here8
your html here9
```

I hope it help

**EDIT 1**

3. file not found issues - try remove `?id=$l` from file name and pass it to `$_GET` array as I suggest above.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The dir issue is a false issue but I will give a try to your hint about passing the variable to the included file!

Comment: I'll mark your answer as ok because the real solution is in the trick you suggested: `$_GET['id'] = $i; include 'businessplan.php';` that is actually what I was asking. Point 1 is not a problem (see also point 3). I knew already that they are caused by trying to pass a query in the url :) Regarding output buffer... this is in the including file and not in the included one (that's why I cannot keep using ajax in this case to load the included files in the including one)