# How to restrict the CSS for only a particular page?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to insert another html page into an php page by using "include"
and that html page is having some stylesheets imported,

**When I insert that page, it disturbs my PHP page..**

How can I restrict the CSS for that particular page only?

Comment: use iframe in that particular page

Comment: split header , body and footer of html page into separate pages

Answer (score 2):

place the imported page inside a container `div`, and then give it an `id` like:

```
<div id='included_page'> Your page goes here...</div>
```

Then add `#included_page .someClass{mystyle: property;}` to each and every style defined.i.e, increase the level.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class or id to each `<body>` and write styles accordingly like below

HTML

```
<body class='home'>
    Home page content
</body>

<body class='about'>
    About page content
</body>
```

CSS

```
.home .someclass{

}
.about .someclass{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**In Page[restrict the CSS]:**

`<?php 
$type = 'exclude'; 
inlcude('page_to_include.php');`

**page_to_include.php:**

`<?php 
if(!isset($type) or ($type !== 'exclude')) {
   // Things to be excluded from Page 1; 
}`

Ref: [PHP - include a php file and also send query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232097/php-include-a-php-file-and-also-send-query-parameters)