# PHP load page issue with php include statement

Tags: php, include

I am trying to include a page using **php include**.

The problems is I need to include a query string and the include call fails, i.e.:

```
<?php include($urlroot.'/discounts/relatedcontent.php');?>
```

retrieves that page successfully but when I try

```
<?php include($urlroot.'/discounts/relatedcontent.php?tag=health');?>
```

the php include call fails.

How come and what can I do about it. I need to pass the value of  tag  to the `$urlroot.'/discounts/relatedcontent.php'`  page

Comment: Is PHP giving any errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - include a php file and also send query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232097/php-include-a-php-file-and-also-send-query-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can't `include` path of file with `GET` parameter. Because `include` get file name as it is and can't handle any rules like `?tag=health`. Instead of this, you need detach part of this script, that generates, when get `?tag=health` and include it separately.