# How do I send dynamic data to template file using sendgrid?

Tags: php, sendgrid

Hi I'm trying to send dynamic data to an external template file using sendgrid like this:

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_KEY'));
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$message_body = file_get_contents('../templates/emails/third-party-booking.php');

$email->addTo(getenv('SENDGRID_EMAIL'))
      ->setFrom("from@email.com")
      ->setSubject("Just a subject here")
      ->setHtml($message_body);

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

How do I send `$details` to the template, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $detail contains some parameters that should be used in your template, you can do it on the $message_body step.

```
$sendgrid = new SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_KEY'));
$email = new SendGrid\Email();
$message_body = file_get_contents('../templates/emails/third-party-booking.php');
// $details = ['name'=>'Jean', 'email'=>'jean@gmail.com'];
// third-party-booking.php content be like 
// <html>...%name%.....%email%...</html>

foreach ($details as $parameter => $value) {
    $message_body= str_replace('%' . $parameter . '%', $value, $message_body);
}

$email->addTo(getenv('SENDGRID_EMAIL'))
      ->setFrom("from@email.com")
      ->setSubject("Just a subject here")
      ->setHtml($message_body);

$sendgrid->send($email);
```

There are no way to send data to a php file as it does a copy of the file content (see [PHP - include a php file and also send query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232097/php-include-a-php-file-and-also-send-query-parameters))

Comment: So I need to install https://github.com/knpuniversity/twig

Comment: if you are using symfony framwork, i suggest you do it. If you are using only php, refer to the documentation link

Comment: I'm using Slim Framework. The documentation shows only examples about using sendgrid templates (using the sendgrid template id) and not using an external html file.

Comment: i've edited my answer to match your requirements